# "Autocomplete off" not working for last control of every web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have on web application with login page, username and password field has attribute autocomplete "off" also tried nope, new-password etc. still its not working in chrome version 62+.
and its ***autocomplete suggestion list reflect on last control of every web page in entire solution***
see below image each control look like this.
Please help me to resolve this issue..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56BQW.png)

Comment: have you saved username and password in browser? From setting you need to remove saved username and password then I guess the autocomplete will not come.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofilling-form-controls%3A-the-autocomplete-attribute):

> A user agent may allow the user to override an element's autofill field name, e.g. to change it from "off" to "on" to allow values to be remembered and prefilled despite the page author's objections, or to always "off", never remembering values.

So, I think you have enabled `autocomplete="on"` in first page and disabling `autocomplete="off"` later wouldn't help you. It will always be **on** once you have enabled it.

Also, `autocomplete="new-password"` support for this value [has not been implemented on Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields).

---

You may also disable the whole form.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

If nothing is working for you, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49984491/2138752) should do the trick:

```
<form autocomplete="false | unknown-autocomplete-value">
```

The `unknown-autocomplete-value` is not known by the browser and will prevent auto fill.

Comment: (autocomplete="false | unknown-autocomplete-value"  )  its also not working . same issue faced.

Comment: make sure you have not enabled autocomplete for the field elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour on most of the modern browsers, so the most popular modern browsers will ignore `autocomplete="off"` on login fields.

> If a site sets autocomplete="off" for username and password fields,
>   then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the
>   user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the
>   user visits the page.

See [The autocomplete attribute and login fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields)

Also see comments on each browser on https://caniuse.com/#search=autocomplete

Some workaround had already been discussed on [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: any solution for it?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill